# Windows Common Controls on expanded nonclient area

Tags: desktop-application

In my applications I want to use common controls (i.e. EDIT, BUTTON COMBOBOXEX32) on non client area which is expanded by DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea. The whole process of expanding works well, but when I use Windows Common Controls on this expanded area, I get nasty effects when text is drawn. After reading a while about this symptom I found out that with GDI+ text is drawn in the composited way, so labels could be drawn with GDI+.

The image below shows a sample. You will watch a split button created by

```
  BStyle = BS_PUSHBUTTON Or WS_CHILD Or WS_VISIBLE Or &HC&
  .hwnd = CreateWindowEX(0, "BUTTON", vbNullString, BStyle, _
                         ScaleLeft, ScaleTop, ScaleWidth, ScaleHeight, _
                         UserControl.hwnd, 0&, App.hInstance, _
                         ByVal 0&)
```

an EDIT also created by CreateWindowEx and a userdrawn button using theming and GDI+ label and image.

The controls created by CreateWindowEx are obviously drawn without support of GDI+ so all content is not properly composited. This is really ugly, because entered text is not readable. It is a big thing to make editors by your own, so I would prefer support of Windows here.

This problem occurs under Win7 to Win10, even there is glossy Win7 background or opaque styles preferred under Win8, Win10.

My question is: Are there any settings in manifest available to set, for drawing common controls properly, or do extended styles exist to support it? Why doesn't windows support it natively?

[Screenshot of common controls on NC area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r83aB.png)

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution with using of the uxtheme buffered paint functions.

On WM_PAINT of the common control do the following:

1. Get the drawing dc by calling BeginPaint
2. call BufferedPaintInit of lib uxtheme
3. Create a buffered paint bitmap by calling BeginBufferedPaint
4. Print the client area of the common control to the buffer
5. Make all pixels of the buffer opaque by BufferedPaintSetAlpha
6. draw the buffer to drawing dc by EndBufferedPaint
7. call BufferedPaintUnInit

For convenience here the code of a classic VB class clsBufferedPaint

```
Option Explicit

Public Enum BP_BUFFERFORMAT
    BPBF_COMPATIBLEBITMAP = 0
    BPBF_DIB = 1
    BPBF_TOPDOWNDIB = 2
    BPBF_TOPDOWNMONODIB = 3
End Enum

Public Enum BP_PAINTPARAMS_FLAGS
    BPPF_ERASE = 1
    BPPF_NOCLIP = 2
    BPPF_NONCLIENT = 4
End Enum

Public Type BP_PAINTPARAMS
    cbSize As Long
    dwFlags As BP_PAINTPARAMS_FLAGS
    prcExclude As Long
    pBlendFunction As Long
End Type

Private mHandle As Long

Private Declare Function BeginBufferedPaint Lib "uxtheme" (ByVal hdcTarget As Long, ByRef prcTarget As RECT, ByVal dwFormat As BP_BUFFERFORMAT, ByRef pPaintParams As Any, ByRef HDC As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function BufferedPaintClear Lib "uxtheme" (ByVal hBufferedPaint As Long, ByRef prc As RECT) As Long
Private Declare Function BufferedPaintInit Lib "uxtheme" () As Long
Private Declare Function BufferedPaintSetAlpha Lib "uxtheme" (ByVal hBufferedPaint As Long, ByRef prc As RECT, ByVal Alpha As Byte) As Long
Private Declare Function BufferedPaintUnInit Lib "uxtheme" () As Long
Private Declare Function EndBufferedPaint Lib "uxtheme.dll" (ByVal hBufferedPaint As Long, ByVal fUpdateTarget As Long) As Long

Friend Function BeginPaint(ByVal targetDC As Long, ByRef targetRect As RECT, _
                  ByVal format As BP_BUFFERFORMAT) As Long
    mHandle = BeginBufferedPaint(targetDC, targetRect, BPBF_TOPDOWNDIB, ByVal 0&, BeginPaint)
End Function

Public Function EndPaint(ByVal updatetargetDC As Long) As Long
    EndPaint = EndBufferedPaint(mHandle, updatetargetDC)
    mHandle = 0
End Function

Friend Sub SetAlpha(ByRef r As RECT, ByVal Alpha As Byte)
    BufferedPaintSetAlpha mHandle, r, Alpha
End Sub


Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    BufferedPaintInit
End Sub


Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    BufferedPaintUnInit
End Sub
```

and using it in WM_PAINT of the common control (has to be subclassed with consuming the message)

```
Dim bp As New clsBufferedPaint, rct As RECT, DC As Long, pDC As Long

GetClientRect hwnd, rct

DC = BeginPaint(hwnd, ps)

pDC = bp.BeginPaint(DC, rct, BPBF_TOPDOWNDIB)
SendMessage hwnd, WM_PRINTCLIENT, pDC, PRF_CLIENT
bp.SetAlpha rct, 255
ISubclass_WindowProc = bp.EndPaint(DC)

EndPaint hwnd, ps
```

Problems to be solved: the corners of the editline are opaque, but they are transparent depending on theme used by the system.

[Editline on non client area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBxtT.png)

Comment: This is not working for multiline style of the edit control